# In Google App Engine datastore (for Python), are ndb key ids by default always integers?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, app-engine-ndb

This appears to be the case, but I am unable to confirm it in the documentation.

The [ndb Key class](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/keyclass) includes methods `id`, `string_id`, and `integer_id`. Of `id`, it states:

> Returns the string or integer id in the last (kind, id) pair, or None if the key is incomplete.

I assume `string_id` only returns a valid id when the Key constructor is explicitly passed a string id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I confirmed that this is the case. It is stated (some might say, buried) in the documentation [here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/entities?hl=en#numeric_keys):

> An application can create an entity without specifying an ID; the Datastore automatically generates a numeric ID.

A code example:

```
from google.appengine.ext import ndb

class Fingerprint(ndb.Model):
    fingerprint = ndb.StringProperty(required=True)

fingerprint = Fingerprint(fingerprint='abc')
new_key = fingerprint.put()
print new_key.id(), type(new_key.id())

fingerprint = Fingerprint(id='abc', fingerprint='abc')
new_key = fingerprint.put()
print new_key.id(), type(new_key.id())

fingerprint = Fingerprint(id=100, fingerprint='abc')
new_key = fingerprint.put()
print new_key.id(), type(new_key.id())
```

Output:

```
4785074604081152 <type 'long'>
abc <type 'str'>
100 <type 'long'>
```